# Yocto build on Raspberry Pi3 stuck on Rainbow screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, linux, kernel, yocto

I am trying to learn about Yocto Project on my Raspberry Pi3 board. I have followed the steps mentioned in this [link](http://mytechpg.blogspot.in/2013/06/raspberrypi-and-yocto.html) to build the Yocto image.

I am behind a firewall, so I have changed the `git.py` file to use `https` instead of `git`. To be precise I have done below changes

Change 1:

```
if 'protocol' in ud.parm:
    ud.proto = ud.parm['protocol']
elif not ud.host:
    ud.proto = 'file'
else:
    #ud.proto = "git"
    ud.proto = "http"
```

Change 2:

```
repourl = "https://%s%s%s" % (username, ud.host, ud.path)
```

I am able to build successfully and have extracted the image on to the SD card as instructed in the link. But after loading the SD card on my Pi board, it is stuck in the initial screen (rainbow screen) and I don't see any logs coming on the serial console.

I have also tried by changing machine variable in the `conf/local.conf` file as mentioned below:

```
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi2"
```

Am not sure what am missing, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your power supply is good then this [elinux.com](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen) website states :

> In some cases (Stuck on the Rainbow Screen), freezing at this point has been fixed by adding "boot_delay=1" to the config.txt file.

There more troubleshooting guide on that page check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found it was because I wasn't using a powerful enough power adapter for the Pi.  It needs to be 2.5A@5V.

When there isn't enough power it hangs on the rainbow screen.

Comment: I think I am using 5v 3.1Amp USB Power Adapter. But, I can confirm tomorrow. Does that rating seems fine ?

Comment: Yeah that is more than enough, your issue must be something else... I hope you find out what it is soon :)

Comment: @user12345 : Even if your power supply is rated correctly they may not supply sufficient power if its faulty or the connecting cable is bad. Only measuring voltage and current will rule out the faulty power supply. Try to swap power supply with different 5V 2.5A rated power supply and also try with different microUSB cable.